Problem: Logistic Regression vs. Tree-based Model Performance on Small Imbalanced Dataset
I have a small dataset with 300 rows and an imbalanced class distribution (35% positives). When I fit a logistic regression model, it consistently performs worse than random chance. I’m using stratified cross-validation to evaluate performance, but I’ve noticed a significant variance in results depending on the data splits.
My current procedure is as follows:

Set aside a holdout test set using stratified k-fold cross-validation.
Use GridSearchCV on the training data to identify the best
hyperparameters for a tree-based model.
Calculate accuracy on the test set.

However, I’ve encountered a problem: Depending on which test set I use, the logistic regression model can outperform the tree-based model selected by GridSearchCV. This seems counterintuitive, as logistic regression has consistently underperformed compared to random chance when evaluated on the full dataset.
Given these observations, I’m concerned that I cannot trust the performance of the holdout test set as an unbiased estimate of the best model. How should I adjust my evaluation procedure to ensure more reliable results, especially when working with such a small and imbalanced dataset?
What strategies would you recommend to address the high variance in model performance across different test splits?

Tree-based models tends to overfit on any data which is accessible. LR can generalise better. It's not always possible to achive good model score in real life (not Kaggle competition). Sometimes it's better to have worse score, but more consistent across different parts of data.
You can use regularisation. Or optimise score in such way, so it have no such big variation across parts of your data. So, you can trust this score, it's more stable. Cross-validation is often useful. And in case you have time-dependent data, you should use different kind of cross-validation, which utilize time factor properly.

The problem is the logistic regression has a pr-auc of <35% which means a blanket classifer that says everything is positive will do better. The precision is only 36% as well. No good. I did a nested CV and the tree-based models actually did perform better on the inner folds and they won each time. Their average performance on the outer loop (to estimate generalizable error) was still better than random chance. So is it safe to go with them now?
